# How to extract value from table function in R

Tags: r, function

I am doing

```
m <- grepl("T00:",test$timestamp)
table(m)
```

and output is

```
m
#FALSE  TRUE 
#966    33
```

I want to assign the value 33 to a variable.. How to do that??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use

```
new_var <- table(m)["TRUE"]
```

to extract the value `33`.