# Extract value from table function in R (no factors)

Tags: r, dataframe

I have this  data frame

```
d1  <- c(1, 0,  0,  1,  0,  0,  0,  1)
d2  <- c(0, 1,  0,  1,  1,  0,  0,  0)
d3  <- c(0, 0,  1,  0,  0,  0,  1,  0)
d4  <- c(0, 0,  0,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0)
d5  <- c(0, 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  0)
d6  <- c(0, 0,  0,  1,  0,  1,  0,  1)
d7  <- c(0, 0,  1,  0,  0,  1,  0,  1)
d8  <- c(1, 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1)
d9  <- c(0, 0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  0,  1)
d10 <- c(1, 1,  0,  0,  0,  1,  0,  1)

df  <- as.data.frame(rbind(d1,d2,d3,d4,d5,d6,d7,d8,d9,d10))

str(df)
```

I  get all lines where V8 == 1, and find the relative frequencies for each column like this (for example column 2, V2):

```
table(df[which(df$V8==1),][2])/sum(as.numeric(df[which(df$V8==1),]$V8))



        0         1 
0.8333333 0.1666667
```

My question is how can I get each relative frequency individually, let's say set it into a new variable. I found this

> [How to extract value from table function in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22643432/how-to-extract-value-from-table-function-in-r)

but it does not work in my case, since 0 and 1 are numericals.

```
table(df[which(df$V8==1),][2])/sum(as.numeric(df[which(df$V8==1),]$V8))["1"]
```

Comment: One method is to store the table, and then extract: `temp <- table(df[which(...` and then `temp["1"]`. Another is to wrap the statement in `()` like this `(table(df[which(df$V8==1),][2])/sum(as.numeric(df[which(df$V8==1),]$V8)))["1"]`.

Comment: @Imo I tried it, it returns the "whole" column, not just 0.1666667

Comment: I think you are a little confuse about the output. The 0 and 1 are actually names of the elements. If you have the temp object, call `names(temp)`. You can strip these with `unname` if you want, but the names don't enter into any calculations. Another way to see this is try `temp["1"] + 5`.

Comment: Using your method @Imo, if I say for instance `2*temp["1"]` I get    `1 
0.3333333`  and not just `0.3333333`.  I was looking for something like asking from my original df to get a single valie using `df[1,1]` which returns `1`

Comment: Please re-read my comment. the 1 is the *name* of the element. As suggested there, you can try `unname(temp["1"])`.

Comment: Ok, it works you are right. Nevertheless, do I have to do it every time? Or can I somehow define `temp` using it?

Comment: Maybe `unname((table(df[which(df$V8==1),][2])/sum(as.numeric(df[which(df$V‌​8==1),]$V8)))["1"])`?

Comment: I  tried it before asking you but it kept returning NAs. Hence I created a function `myfunction <- function(x,y) {
  temp <- table(df[which(df$V8==1),][x])/sum(as.numeric(df[which(df$V8==1),]$V8))
  unname(temp[y])
}` and it works! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

use as.numeric, and then, after that, change them to ratios
the numbers 0 and 1 are extracted with 
    as.numeric(names(table(data)))
and the numbers 64 and 17 are extracted with 
    counts<-as.numeric(table(data))
then 
    ratios<-counts/sum(counts)

Answer (score 0):

Not completely sure about what you're trying to do but...

```
sapply(subset(df, V8==1), function(x) sum(x==1)/length(x))
```